# SQL Search for substring date

Tags: sql

I'm trying to filter my SQL results for a date on a specific year.

The dates are stored in a single column DATE in the format month/day/year

I need to only grab the result for certain years.

```
String sql = SELECT DATE FROM TABLENAME
WHERE **LAST TWO DATE DIGITS** = ? ORDER BY DATE DESC;

ps.setString(1, yearDesired);
```

Is this possible? I have been looking around and haven't found an issue directly related to this.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: which sql database are you using

Comment: What's the type of DATE? I would assume it's datetime, but since you mention that it's stored in M/D/Y order, and you mention substring in the question title, maybe it's a char or varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several databases support the `YEAR()` function:

```
WHERE  YEAR(dtColumn) between 2003 and 2005
```

For a more specific answer, post the database you're using.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, but this works great for my situation. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL implementations have date functions, e.g. YEAR(DATE) would return the 4 digit year.

[SQL Date Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName where DatePart(YY, myDateColumn) = 2013
```